# Order cancel from admin taking time in magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9

How to speed up order cancel from admin when we cancel the order.

**Scenario:** when we cancel order from admin order view its taking time, so how to resolve this?

Comment: It would be a good thing to find out what is the cause of it being slow, have you investigated anything on your own? How long does the database deletes take? Because I think that's a good place to start.

Comment: i checked query time also,which is fine

Comment: Is it in `local` or `live`

Comment: LIve have test in local